# Moving WKWebview frame causes part of it to become unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I have a toolbar on top of a WKWebView. It looks as follows below. There are constraints that put the ToolBar above the webview(See Below). The webview looks as follows and the black line is drawn in to separate the toolbar and webview, but is not part of the app.

[image]

On some of the pages within the app I want to remove the toolbar. I use the following code below to do so:

```
    let toolBarNF = CGRect(x: 0 , y: -44 , width: toolBar.frame.width , height:44)
    toolBar.frame = toolBarNF

    let webViewNF = CGRect(x: 0 , y: -44 , width: webView.frame.width , height: (originalWHeight + originalTHeight))
    webView.frame = webViewNF
```

Where `originalWHeight` is the original height of the webview and `originalTheight` is the original height of the toolbar.

This produced the following frame:

[image]

The issue I discovered is by moving the webview frame up 44 pixels, the top 44 pixels of the WKWebview become unclickable and unresponsive. So none of my menu buttons work unless you click toward the bottom of them. I think there is something built in to "lock" the responsive overlay to it, but I don't really know enough about that. It could also be the toolbar overlays but I don't know enough about that.

Another important thing as well, the buttons elsewhere seem to work in the correct location, meaning that I don't need to click 44 pixels up from where they should be.

One thing I tried was updating the constraints via using             `webView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` with this view and others within the app,  but this didn't work.

Below are constraints in my view(these two views are in container view)

[image]

Does anyone know a solution to this or anything that can help me out? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Why are you manually editing the frames when you're using auto layout?

Comment: Because I don't know any better otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. The toolbar is automatically set to 44 pixels in height by default so it is the same across all the devices. How would you go about it so that I could have the layout set automatically( or manually) and then move the toolbar and WKWebview to the proper position?

Comment: You need to change the constraints (or the constraint constants). Generally you'd pin the views together and then move the top view off screen

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use Autolayout

1. Anchor `toolbar.Top` to `Top Layout Guide.Bottom`
2. Anchor `webview.Top` to `toolbar.bottom`

To change the location of the toolbar (*and hence its hidden status*), change the `constant` of the constraint #1. You need a reference to that constraint, `toolbarTopAnchor` in the present example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbarTopAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
var toolbarVisible = true

@IBAction func doToggleVisibility(_ sender: Any) {
    toolbarVisible = !toolbarVisible
    toolbarTopAnchor.constant = ((toolbarVisible) ? 0 : -44)
}
```

[image: animation]
[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jLgH.gif)

---

#### Further recommendations

1. Do not hardcode the height of the toolbar

   ```
   self.toolbarTopAnchor.constant = ((self.toolbarVisible)
       ? 0
       : -self.toolbar.frame.height) // Not hardcoded
   ```
2. Animate the transition

   ```
   @IBAction func doToggleVisibility(_ sender: Any) {
       toolbarVisible = !toolbarVisible
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { 
           self.toolbarTopAnchor.constant = ((self.toolbarVisible)
               ? 0
               : -self.toolbar.frame.height)
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
   }
   ```
3. You may want to insert a cover in between the status bar and the tool bar. This is achieved with zero lines of code in Interface Builder.

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-41291054) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-41291054).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!